# Give options to user to select from PHP command line application

Tags: php, command-line

I'm creating an application in which I want some input from user which I achieved by using readline function

```
<?php
$input = readline("Some input is required "": ");
echo $input
?>
```

which is working absolutely but the problem is I think if people can do typing mistake and I've some limited options let's say 5 options I want just that as input

but in this case user have free hands and he can write anything but I want user to show options like

```
Here is some question :  
option a  
option b 
option c 
option d 
option e
```

now I want user to select any option from these 5 only but I'm not able to find any function for it

Please let me know if its achievable or not possible in PHP

Comment: `if (!in_array($input, ['a', 'b', ...])) echo 'Try again';`, then ask the user again for input (in a loop)…!?

Comment: see how [climate](https://climate.thephpleague.com/terminal-objects/input/) does it, or just use the package

Comment: @LawrenceCherone thanks looks like what I want but I just need to check how it works so that I can use options directly instead of using full package

Comment: Also note that [Symfony Console Component](https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/console.html) provides you ready to use features like questions, choices and colors. But in general having interactive menus in CLI for me only worked either in shell or cmd but rarely both.

Comment: Instead of using 'readline' can't you just present the user with a HTML page that contains a select element with the options you want?  After the user selects an option and submits it you're off to the races.